# Combinatorics question - watching exactly two movies in a row

Tags: combinatorics

The question is:

> Atticus has three comedies, two dramas and an action movie. He decides that he wants to watch two, and only two, comedies in a row.
>   In how many ways can Atticus watch his six movies?

The given answer is $432$.

My attempts:

**Attempt 1**:

The number of ways in which he can watch at least two comedies in a row can be given by fixing two of them together:

$C_1\,X_1\,(C_2\,C_3)\,X_2\,X_3$ ($5!\cdot3!$)

Then we subtract the number of ways he watches all three comedies in a row:

$X_1\,(C_1\,C_2\,C_3)\,X_2\,X_3$ ($4!\cdot3!$)

$5!\cdot3!-4!\cdot3!=576\neq 432$

**Attempt 2**:

There are $6!$ ways he can watch movies without any restriction.

There are $4!\cdot3!$ ways he can watch all three comedies in a row.

The number of ways he watches exactly one comedy in a row is:

$C_1\,X_1\,C_2\,X_2\,C_3\,X_3$ ($3!\cdot3!$)

$X_1\,C_1\,X_2\,C_2\,X_3\,C_3$ ($3!\cdot3!$)

So to find the ways in which he watches exactly two comedies in a row we can take the total without restriction and subtract the number of ways he can watch, exactly, either one or three comedies in a row.

$6!-2\cdot (3!)^2 -4!\cdot3! = 504 \neq 432$

What cases am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange the non-comedy first, there are $3$ of them: $\color{blue}{3!}$. Denote them as $N$.

$$XNXNXNX$$

where $X$ are slots to place the comedies, let me tie up two comedies together. Hence I have two block of comedies, one consists of one comedy and one consists of two. number of ways to form the block: $\color{blue}{\binom{3}{1}}$

Each $X$ can take in at most one block. Also, remember that we can change the order within the block: $$2! \cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot 2$$

Hence in total

$$3! \cdot 3 \cdot  2! \cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot 2 = 6(3)(2)(6)(2)=432$$

Edit:

Remark for attempt $1$:

Have you remove over counting like  $(C_1C_2)C_3$ and $C_1(C_2C_3)$?

Remark for attempt $2$:

Have you considered cases like $C_1X_1X_2C_2X_3C_3$?

Number of ways to watch exactly one movie can be counted by arranging $X$ first $3!$ and then prepare slots to insert exactly one comedy, there are $4$ slots. $\binom{4}{3}\cdot 3!$

Hence $$6!-4(3!)^2-4!3!=432$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it - but could you tell me why my attempts were wrong?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.